# When opening my MacBook Pro, the Superdrive makes noise

Tags: macbook-pro, optical-drive

I have a MacBook Pro mid-2012 and I love the easy way of putting it to sleep when closing the laptop. I have never used the SuperDrive.

The problem is that after several months of using it and getting it out of sleep correctly when I open the screen, now when I open the screen, the SuperDrive makes noise, just like at startup. It never did that before.

I hate having such a noise when coming out from sleep. Is there a way to disable the SuperDrive?

Answer (score 2):

There's an option to disable Super-drive in parental controls. Check in `system preferences` -> `Parental control`.

**Edit**
Ok if you want to do completely disable the superdrive without playing with parental control you can do it by unloading the kext file. Just go to `/System/Library/Extensions` folder and find `IODVDStorageFamily.kext` file. Move this file to any alternate location or create a new folder there itself and put it there and reboot. You won't see the superdrive in your connected devices again.

To use the superdrive again, you need to put that file again on the same location and insert a USB drive, so that OSX starts searching for connected devices and it'll find your superdrive. Do take the backup of you kext file properly and do not delete it.

Comment: I can't test this but it's likely to be a software protection only, not a hardware disable switch, especially because the admin account has full privileges, including accessing the Superdrive.

Comment: yes i would like to completely disable it without putting parental controls on my administrator account .. is there a bios setting ??

Comment: added another option. Do check it out

Comment: i have just tried that : put a cd in the superdrive after reboot and it doesn't appear anywhere.. it seems ok but i will close my MacBook and try to get it from sleep to see if it still makes noise... I wish i could disable it completely instead of just removing the driver